# How can I bind to an element, inside a list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a List that I wish to bind to internal values.

```
public class LogEntryList
{
    public List<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }
    public LogEntryList() { LogEntries = new List<LogEntry>(); }
}
public class LogEntry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public Brush BgColor { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public double Type { get; set; }
}
```

```
logEntryList.LogEntries.Add(new LogEntry { Name = "Exception 2", Type = 02 });
logEntryList.LogEntries.Add(new LogEntry { Name = "Exception 7", Type = 07 });
```

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" DataContext="logEntryList">
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding ElementName="logEntryList" Path="LogEntries" Mode="OneWay" />
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Purple">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">Name:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

How can I bind my ListBoxItems to the values of Name, and Data, etc.?

Comment: `DataContext="logEntryList"` and `ElementName="logEntryList"` are pointless. Assign a LogEntryList instance to the DataContext of the Window, like `DataContext = new LogEntryList();`.

Comment: Also, attribute sytax for the Binding is shorter: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntries}" ...>`. As a first step, read [Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview). Don't try to code "something" without knowing what it means. That won't work with WPF.

Comment: @Clemens Right, thanks. I was overthinking what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using Window DataContext as per Clemens comment.

```
public class LogEntryList
{
    public List<LogEntry> LogEntries { get; set; }
    public LogEntryList() { LogEntries = new List<LogEntry>(); }
}
public class LogEntry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public Brush BgColor { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public double Type { get; set; }
}
```

```
DataContext = logEntryList;
logEntryList.LogEntries.Add(new LogEntry { Name = "Exception 2", Type = 02 });
logEntryList.LogEntries.Add(new LogEntry { Name = "Exception 7", Type = 07 });
```

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Background="DarkGray" ItemsSource="{Binding LogEntries}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Purple">Name:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Purple">Name:</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Type}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```